# Detecting red balls in a basket scalar value wont work

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect red balls in a basket through thresholding . My problem is I think I have the wrong Scalar values because the result is just black.I am not sure which vector channel is the luminance,hue,saturation and brightness

```
enter code here
 Mat  onespoon= image[2];
 Mat onespoonnewcolor;
 Mat newspoon;

 cvtColor(onespoon, onespoonnewcolor, CV_BGR2HSV);

 inRange(onespoonnewcolor, Scalar(30,0,60,30), Scalar(70,7,100,70), newspoon);
 namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for     display.
 imshow( "Display window", newspoon );                   // Show our image inside it.
```

Comment: pls post an example img

Answer (score 3):

You are converting to HSV color space. That means the first, second, and third image channels correspond to hue, saturation, and value. There is no fourth channel, so your `Scalar` arguments should have only three elements.

In OpenCV, hue ranges from 0 to 180, and saturation and value range from 0 to 255.

Without a posted example image, I can only guess a range for the correct [hue angles](http://www.comfsm.fm/~dleeling/statistics/s53/farawayrainbow.html). This suggests that hue values in the ranges `[0, 15]` and `[165,180]` might work well. Since red wraps around the zero-point of the spectrum, this would require two applications of `cv::inRange()`. For hue and saturation, I would discard low values, using the range `[20,255]`.

Your code might then look like this, after which `newspoon` contains the results of both `inRange` passes:

```
cv::Mat temp1, temp2;
cv::inRange(onespoonnewcolor, cv::Scalar(0,20,20), cv::Scalar(15,255,255), temp1);
cv::inRange(onespoonnewcolor, cv::Scalar(165,20,20), cv::Scalar(180,255,255), temp2);
cv::Mat newspoon;
cv::bitwise_or(temp1, temp2, newspoon);
```

As pointed out in the comments, it is possible to do this with only a single call to `inRange()`, which is more efficient and eliminates some temporary variables:

```
cv::Mat newspoon;
cv::inRange(onespoonnewcolor, cv::Scalar(16,20,20), cv::Scalar(164,255,255), newspoon);
newspoon = 255 - newspoon;
```

Comment: Do you mind showing me what you meant by applying the inRange twice.

Comment: You could do this with one call to InRange like this `cv::inRange(onespoonnewcolor, cv::Scalar(16,20,20), cv::Scalar(164,255,255), temp1);  cv::Mat newspoon = 255 - temp1;`