# use Opencv to find red color in a picture

Tags: java, opencv

I try to use opencv to find red color in photos. However, it ended a totally black photo every time.

I find all the red, blue, and green color in the picture. Then, I divide the three img green, red, and blue.

Down is my code,

```
Mat mat1 = new Mat();
  mat1 = Highgui.imread("test2.jpg");
  int h = mat1.height();
  int w = mat1.width();

  Mat temp8u = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC1);
  Mat imgR =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat imgG =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat imgB =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat temp =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat temp1 =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);  
  Mat temp2 =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat temp3 =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Mat temp4 =  new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_32FC1);

  List<Mat> listImg = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
  Core.split(mat1, listImg);
  Mat imgR8u = listImg.get(0);  
  Mat imgG8u = listImg.get(1); 
  Mat imgB8u = listImg.get(2);
  imgR8u.convertTo(imgR, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  imgG8u.convertTo(imgG, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  imgB8u.convertTo(imgB, CvType.CV_32FC1);

  int size = (int) (imgR.total() * imgR.channels());                //方法2
  float[] buff = new float[size];
  imgR.get(0, 0, buff);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (buff[i] > 200)
        buff[i] = (float) 255;
    else
        buff[i] = (float) 0;
    //buff[i] = (byte) (255 - buff[i]);
  temp1.put(0, 0, buff);

  Core.add(imgR,imgG,temp);
  Core.add(temp,imgB,temp);
  Core.add(temp, new Scalar(1,1,1), temp);
  Core.divide(imgR,temp,temp2);
  Imgproc.threshold(temp2, temp2,0.37,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

  Core.divide(imgG,temp,temp3);
  Imgproc.threshold(temp3,temp3,0.30,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

  Core.divide(imgB,temp,temp4);
  Imgproc.threshold(temp4,temp4,0.32,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

  Core.bitwise_and(temp1,temp2,temp2);
  Core.bitwise_and(temp2,temp3,temp3);
  Core.bitwise_and(temp3,temp4,temp);

  temp.convertTo(temp8u, CvType.CV_8UC1);

  Highgui.imwrite("Threshold.jpg", temp8u);
```

How come my final pictures, Threshold.jpg, are all black?

Comment: Plus, I can get right photo for imgR, imgG, imgB
As for temp2, temp3, temp4, nothing!

Comment: Remember that 8UC1 has value in range [0;255] and 32FC1 in Range [0.0; 1.0]. I think the problem is that when you convert 8UC1 to 32FC1 you just change type to float but value remain 255.0. You have to scale it to be in desired range.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430013/detecting-red-balls-in-a-basket-scalar-value-wont-work